# What are the Invalid Actions & Invalid Conditions options in Decision Table Creator?

Tags: testcase, validation

If you click `View` in [Decision Table Creator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/decisiontablecr/) and select either "`Invalid Actions`" or "`Invalid Conditions`", what is that supposed to tell you?

Both either highlight all of my `Actions` or all of my `Conditions`, respectively.

I wonder if it's because it's using some sort of default evaluation.

Does anyone know if this software can be extended?

Comment: I am not sure this question fits the SQA site's scope, probably [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: It fits the scope, but Software Recommendations or SuperUser may be able to give better answers. The project appears to be dead, since the code hasn't updated since 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The Invalid Actions and Invalid Conditions options in Decision Table Creator are likely features that allow you to view and identify any actions or conditions in your decision table that may be invalid or not meeting the specified criteria. When you select either of these options, the software likely highlights all actions or conditions that it considers to be invalid, so that you can review and make any necessary changes.

It is possible that the software is using a default evaluation to determine which actions or conditions are invalid, but without more information about the specific software you are using, it is difficult to say for sure.

In general, most software can be extended or customized through the use of plugins or extensions. However, whether or not a particular piece of software can be extended would depend on the specific features and capabilities of that software. It would be best to consult the documentation or support resources for the Decision Table Creator software to see if it has any options for extending its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In Decision Table Creator, "Invalid Actions" and "Invalid Conditions" options are used to identify any issues or inconsistencies in defined actions or conditions within decision table. Let's understand their purpose:

1. Invalid Actions: When you select "Invalid Actions" option, Decision Table Creator highlights any actions in table that might be invalid or have inconsistencies. This could include actions that are not defined properly, have missing values, or violate any specified rules or constraints.

For example, if you have a rule that states "If Condition A is true, then Action X should be performed," but in your decision table, Action X is not associated with Condition A, it would be considered an invalid action. The Decision Table Creator would highlight such inconsistencies to help you identify and rectify them.

2. Invalid Conditions: On the other hand, selecting the "Invalid Conditions" option highlights any conditions in decision table that might be invalid or have inconsistencies. It helps you identify conditions that are not defined properly, have missing values, or do not align with specified rules or constraints.

For instance, if you have a condition that checks for the value of a variable, but the variable is not defined or used incorrectly in the decision table, it would be considered an invalid condition. The Decision Table Creator would highlight such inconsistencies to assist you in resolving them.

By using the "Invalid Actions" and "Invalid Conditions" options, you can easily spot any potential errors or inconsistencies in your decision table, ensuring its accuracy and reliability.

Regarding the extensibility of the software, it depends on the specific Decision Table Creator tool you are using. Some decision table tools offer extension capabilities, allowing you to customize or enhance the functionality based on your requirements. You may need to refer to the documentation or explore the tool's features to determine if it can be extended to meet your specific needs.

Remember to consult the user manual or documentation provided with the Decision Table Creator tool for detailed information on its features, including extension possibilities.